# Fedex Ruby Mechanize: Unable to log in

Tags: ruby, authentication, mechanize, fedex

I'm trying to automate my fedex processing via Ruby gem Mechanize.
I've set up the initial script similar to what has worked for me on the Amazon Seller Central page. However, I seem to be unable to fully log in to the fedex website and I appear to just be "staying" on the login page.

If you have any idea what my code is missing, it would be appreciated!

CODE

```
Dir.chdir 'C:\Ruby22\bin'
require "rubygems"
require "mechanize"
require "certified"
require "logger"

#Initialize and set agent settings:
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
agent.redirect_ok = true

#Log in to fedex
login_url = "https://www.fedex.com/dk/"
page_login = agent.get(login_url)
puts "Login Page: " + page_login.title.to_s

form = page_login.form_with(:name => "logonForm")
#form.fields.each { |f| puts f.name }
form.username = "************"
form['ap_signin_existing_radio'] = "1"
form.password = "*********"
agent.submit(form)
page_home = agent.get(login_url)
puts "Fedex Dashboard Page: " + page_home.title
```

Comment: FWIW: mechanize doesn't support javascript, so you may want to look at a webdriver-based approach (e.g. selenium, watir).

Comment: Adding to what @orde said, you do probably need a web driver for storing sessions and so on, which is usually used to detect if you're authenticated or not. I've done something similar in the past using [Capybara with Poltergeist](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#poltergeist).